# coreplot Xaxis start value iOS 7

Tags: ios, graph, core-plot, stacked-area-chart

[image: Area Chart]

I am developing an Area chart like the following and facing the following issue.

- curve shape is not looking proper, i need a smooth curve.
- X-axis values are Dynamic, it May start with 40 or May be 60 or
  any other value.how to calculate that ?

Any Help will be greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the line smoother, either give it more data points or make a curved plot.

```
plot.interpolation = CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved;
```

If you know the range of data values, just set the `xRange` directly. Remember to set the location to the `min` value and the length to `(max - min)`. You can also have the graph scale the plot space for you.

```
[plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[graph allPlots]];
```